# Verify Maven dependencies Jars (.class files) compiled from open source

Tags: java, maven, security, jar, pgp

I would like to verify that Jar (.class) files were compiled from the same source which is available online or even in the Jar itself.
Theoretically someone can upload a compiled Jar to Maven repository sign it with PGP. But the compiled content might be different from the source that it was uploaded with, and contain a malware (see [example](https://blog.malwarebytes.org/intelligence/2013/04/malware-in-a-jar/) and [another one](http://blog.bintray.com/2014/08/04/feel-secure-with-ssl-think-again/)).

How can I verify the integrity of compiled content inside jars which can be found in my Maven dependencies?

This problem might happen even though I have downloaded the signed Jar through HTTPS from known repository as Maven. The secure way which I may think of is to compile the available source code of all dependencies and use the output.

Comment: Hello, it has been long since you have posted this question. I have a similar question about verifying changes made to the compiled content. Do you know/remember the solution which you got? thanks

Answer (score 0):

From some time maven build can be reproducible - it means that if you get source code and build locally - result will be the same bit by bit.

More info can be found at:

- https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/jvm/
- https://github.com/jvm-repo-rebuild/reproducible-central
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-reproducible-builds.html